# Django admin error "Please correct the errors below."

Tags: django, django-admin, django-custom-user, django-custom-manager

I have made custom BaseUserManager to create user but I am getting error of "please  correct the errors below" when I add user from django admin panel and I can't find what's going wrong.

Models.py:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self,email,password):
        user = self.model(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)

    def create_superuser(self,email,password):
        user = self.model(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.save(using=self._db)




class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):

    COMPANY='CO'
    EMPLOYEE='EM'
    STATUS_CHOICES=(
        (COMPANY,'Company'),
        (EMPLOYEE,'Employee'),
    )
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=2,
                            choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                            default=EMPLOYEE)
    user_image = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_admin=models.BooleanField()
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_staff=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    object = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects=models.Manager()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
```

Admin.py files:

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password','Status','user_image','last_login')}),

        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin','is_staff','is_superuser','user_permissions','groups')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets= (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password','Status','user_image','last_login')}),

        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin','is_staff','is_superuser','user_permissions','groups')}),
    )

    search_fields = ('password',)
    ordering = ('password',)
    filter_horizontal = ()



admin.site.register(User,UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Company)
admin.site.register(Employee)
admin.site.register(Job)
admin.site.register(AppliedJobs)
```

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong? I always get the error when I add user from admin panel.I can't figure out as I am working first time on baseusermanager.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and answer is pretty simple.

The problem is in your `add_fieldsets`. Django use his own pattern for adding new users (you can check it in `UserAdmin` model in `django.contrib.auth.admin.py` file). You need to define fields for `password1` and `password2`.

For your convenience I will paste it there:

```
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2'),
    }),
)
```

Here you have 2 options: 
P.S. in any case you need to define `username`, `password1` and `password2` fields.

1. Use superclass field and add your custom:

```
add_fieldsets = UserAdmin.add_fieldsets + (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'Status', 'user_image', 'last_login')}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions', 'groups')}),
)
```

2. Define by your own:

```
add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'Status', 'user_image', 'last_login')}),
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'user_permissions', 'groups')}),
)
```

Comment: This was a problem ! I had only 'password' in my add_fieldsets and it was throwing the error. thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest how to try and find the problem. Usually, your `UserAdmin` will refer to forms, see below:

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = SignUpForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
```

You can find out what is causing the errors by using logging. Add the following Mixin to your `SignUpForm` and `CustomUserChangeForm`:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833638/how-to-log-all-django-form-validation-errors
class LoggingMixin(object):
    def add_error(self, field, error):
        if field:
            logger.info('Form error on field %s: %s', field, error)
        else:
            logger.info('Form error: %s', error)
        super().add_error(field, error)

# e.g.
class SignUpForm(LoggingMixin, UserCreationForm):
    ....
```

Now, either sign in or change a user and check the logs to find out what is causing the "Please correct the errors below.".