# How to log all Django serializer validation errors?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833638/how-to-log-all-django-form-validation-errors), I would like to get log lines on the server when [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers) validation fails.

What is the best approach to add logging to Serializers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be done with a custom exception handler (see [Django REST Framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)), which would apply to all DRF endpoints (if you want it for all Django endpoints, then you should use custom middleware):

```py
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Get standard error response from REST framework's default exception handler:
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is not None and response.status_code == http.client.BAD_REQUEST:
        # Log response data for bad request to simplify debugging:
        logger.warning(f"Bad request to {context['request'].path}: {response.data}")

    return response
```

You'll also need to register this handler, as described in the [Django REST Framework docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling).

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to override the `is_valid` call.

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        ...

    def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
        ret = super(MySerializer, self).is_valid(False)
        if self._errors:
            logger.warn("Serialization failed due to {}".format(self.errors))
            if raise_exception:
                raise ValidationError(self.errors)
        return ret
```